# Throttle Azure storage account events

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid, azure-storage-account

I have a storage account event configured with below setup

Whenever a blob is crated in a container, it will invoke a subscription which is an Event Grid triggered function App.

I would like to throttle so that at any time only one event is raised from the storage account and one execution of the function happens at any time to avoid concurrency issues.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Events are tied to a specific storage action, and only a single event will be sent. Please edit to clarify.

Comment: I don't think there's a way for you to do that, unless you implement it. The consumer of the first event just add a flag somewhere which will let the other consumers know it's been processed. Once you finish, you 'release' / clear the flag and another event will be able to be consumed

Comment: The whole point of the event driven system is so that bottlenecks don't occur and it sounds like you're wanting to build one in.  My suggestion would be to proxy the trigger using your current function and then put that blob name/location on to a storage queue.  Then create another function with your current logic which is triggered by the queue but only processes one message at a time.  Not sure if that helps or not.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#hostjson-settings

Comment: The queue will likely build up and never clear though if you create this bottleneck and your stream is fairly constant.

Comment: yeah, thanks for suggesting this

Comment: @Thiago Custodio, I will see if this can be handled at implementation side.